# I don't understand Chi Squared Test for Goodness of Fit

Tags: categorical-data, chi-squared-test, sample, nonparametric

I have a sample of 45 females and 30 males. I want to say something about gender distribution in the sample, and whether it accurately reflects the population.

I have a very limited knowledge of statistical tests. But I think I should be using Chi Squared Goodness of Fit.

Everything I read is slightly different though. I can find lots of examples where we are interested in two variables (e.g. males vs females + smiling vs non-smiling) but I just want to say something about the males vs females.

I will leave it at that for now as not to muddy the waters. But if anyone needs more clarification in order to help please let me know!

Thanks

Marc

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: It's impossible to determine whether this gender ratio of 45:30 "accurately reflects the population" unless either (1) you have independent information about the ratio within the population or (2) you rigorously followed some kind of sampling procedure that would assure the sample ratio reflected that of the population.  If you could supply information about either of these, then your question could be answerable.